# Calculate distance from polygon feature centroid to coordinate in QGIS 3.18

Tags: qgis, polygon, field-calculator, centroids

I have a shapefile with a lot of polygon features in it. For each polygon, I want to calculate the distance from the centroid of each polygon to a certain coordinate.

How can I achieve this using the field calculator?

[image]

See the added picture for an example: For every feature, I want the distance from its centroid to the red dot (CRS projection I used is EPSG28992, but regular lon lat is also fine. As long as the distance gets calculated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use something like:

```
distance( centroid( $geometry ),  geom_from_wkt( 'POINT(350000 650000)'))
```

if you have a simple fixed point.

Comment: Everyone gave great suggestions and the problem was fairly simple i assume. I ended up using this solution, since it was the most intuitive for me. 

Thanks!

Comment: lol ... there was something like a "race" for answering ... that's the beauty of SE ...

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following should be working :

```
distance(st_centroid($geometry),getfeature(point_layer_name, id, 1)
```

**getfeature(point_layer_name,id, 1)** is a way to retrieve your 'reference' point (based on its id=1 in that case) ... adapt it to your table's structure ...

Comment: `distance($centroid,make_point(x-coord,y-coord))` works, too.

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression: `length (make_line (centroid ($geometry), make_point ([x], [y])))`
replace `[x]` and `[y]` with the x- and y-coordinates values of your reference point. Be sure to have an appropriate CRS (a projected one) and use the same CRS for your points and the coordinates of your reference point.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like:

1. using the [`geom_from_wkt()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#geom-from-wkt)

   ```
   length(shortest_line(centroid($geometry), geom_from_wkt('POINT(508503.622 5406706.511)')))
   ```
2. or using the [`make_point()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#make-point)

   ```
   length(shortest_line(centroid($geometry), make_point(508503.622,5406706.511)))
   ```